# jQuery Mobile; twentytwenty plugin will only show up when the browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this is happening, as I've followed the directions on Zurb's website. It doesn't matter what size the window is upon opening the page with TwentyTwenty, it will only show the slider once the page has been resized. The plugin works flawlessly aside from that. I have a feeling there's some way to adjust the following to make it load without resizing the window...

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();
});
```

Maybe? Much appreciated.

Comment: Nope. Never did, sorry. It was for a project in school, I just ended up resizing the window quickly before presenting it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bug, but fixed by add code. 
Add this to jquery.twentytwenty.js file:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   $(window).trigger("resize.twentytwenty");
});
```

```js
  $.fn.twentytwenty = function(options) {
     var options = $.extend({default_offset_pct: 0.5, orientation: 'horizontal'}, options);

    // >>>>> HERE ADD CODE <<<<<<

     return this.each(function() {
```

//.......

source: https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty/pull/69/commits/471a824bf5ab233797d0de689a5be105347c81e2

Answer (score -1):

I've sat on this same issue for a long time. I was using the class to `.twentytwenty-container` in the code. When I switched it to an id (here, `#container-id`), the issue seemed to go away.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#container-id").twentytwenty({
    default_offset_pct: 0.5, // How much of the before image is visible when the page loads
    orientation: 'horizontal' // Orientation of the before and after images ('horizontal' or 'vertical')
  });
});
```

Does this work for anyone else?